# Blank Page is displayed on launching Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

Blank Web page is displayed after initial Loading messages when Hyperledger Explorer is configured.

Versions:
Versions (pretty much latest stable version):
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Docker: 18.03.0-ce
Node: v9.11.1
Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1.0
Hyperledger Composer: 0.19

```
{
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "events": "grpc://localhost:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/pwc/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/pwc/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }
},
"host": "localhost",
"port": "8085",
"channel": "composerchannel",
"keyValueStore": "/home/pwc/.composer-credentials",
"eventWaitTime": "30000",
"users":[
    {
       "username":"admin",
       "secret":"adminpw"
    }
 ],
"pg": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "5432",
    "database": "fabricexplorer",
    "username": "hppoc",
    "passwd": "password"
},
"license": "Apache-2.0"
```

}

Docker Containers Running on System:
[image: image of Docker Containers Running on System]

`Config.json` File:
[image: image of Config.json File]

Logs in `Log.log` file:

> ```
> postgres://hppoc:password@localhost:5432/fabricexplorer
> Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:8085/
> Insert sql is INSERT INTO chaincodes  ( "name","version","path","channelname" ) VALUES( $1,$2,$3,$4  ) RETURNING *;
> INSERT ID: 20
> Insert sql is INSERT INTO blocks  ( "blocknum","channelname","prehash","datahash","txcount","createdt" ) VALUES( $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6  ) RETURNING *;
> INSERT ID: 8
> Insert sql is INSERT INTO transaction  ( "channelname","blockid","txhash","createdt","chaincodename","chaincode_id","status","creator_msp_id","endorser_msp_id","type","read_set","write_set" ) VALUES( $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12  ) RETURNING *;
> INSERT ID: 13
> ```

Tried with solutions mentioned in below links, but it did not help:
[Hyperledger Explorer + Composer not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071713/hyperledger-explorer-composer-not-showing-data)

Comment: Any js errors in F12 tools?

Comment: I have a similar situation, and the F12 log shows that there was a timeout for the /api/channels endpoint

Comment: Timeout error is displayed in the browser logs on Developer tools. The data seems to be in the Database but is not displayed in the UI.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

which version of Hyperledger Explorer are you using? V0.3.5?
You may need to downgrade your node version to 8.X (9 is not supported, at least for V0.3.5)

Also, if your UI is blank, it could be you missed the "npm run build" step